# Entity Framework Inheritance Mapping (TPH)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm working on converting a project from nHibernate to Entity Framework and stuck on a mapping issue with mapping an inheritance.

I have the following base class (shortened for brevity):

```
public abstract class Status
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectStatus : Status
{ 

}

public class TaskStatus : Status 
{

}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction for how to write the mappings for `TaskStatus` and `ProjectStatus` to inherit from `Status`?  I would like to use table-per-hierarchy (all saved in one table using a Discriminator)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Table Per Hierarchy is the default. You shouldn't need to provide any additional setup besides what you already have.

This is taken from the TPH example from [weblogs.asp.net](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph):

```
public abstract class BillingDetail 
{
    public int BillingDetailId { get; set; }
    public string Owner { get; set; }        
    public string Number { get; set; }
}

public class BankAccount : BillingDetail
{
    public string BankName { get; set; }
    public string Swift { get; set; }
}

public class CreditCard : BillingDetail
{
    public int CardType { get; set; }                
    public string ExpiryMonth { get; set; }
    public string ExpiryYear { get; set; }
}

public class InheritanceMappingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<BillingDetail> BillingDetails { get; set; }
}
```

This will create a single table called BillingDetails with a discriminator column.

> Discriminator Column
>
> As you can see in the DB schema above, Code First has to add a special
>   column to distinguish between persistent classes: the discriminator.
>   This isn’t a property of the persistent class in our object model;
>   it’s used internally by EF Code First. By default, the column name is
>   "Discriminator", and its type is string. The values defaults to the
>   persistent class names —in this case, “BankAccount” or “CreditCard”.
>   EF Code First automatically sets and retrieves the discriminator
>   values.