# Map to class based on property value

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

Say I have two classes

```
class Employee 
{
    public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public int Manager { get; set; }
}

class Manager : Employee 
{

}
```

where `int Manager` can be either `1` or `0`. I want to create a mapping in my `EmployeeContext` so that employee entries in the employee table, where manager equals 1, are mapped to the `Manager` class.

Comment: Why not get rid of the manager class and add a bool to the employees class telling you if that employee is a manager. The above does not look like a good way to code like that to me.

Comment: I have other classes that require employees to be managers. I figured if I could create this mapping then there are a whole lot of checks I could eliminate. Plus, the database schema is already created.

Comment: If you have a business class or a main class I would create an add method in that main class to handle the adding of managers and employees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a TPH inheritance pattern as described [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph).
What you need to add to the described implementation is - you need to include the `Discriminator` property in your entity classes and map it to the according database field. Then implement your `int Manager` according to the value of the `Discriminator` property - and `Manager` can only be a read-only property.

If you want to make the employee a manager you must change the value of the `Discriminator` field. In turn, you must be aware of what's happening in your db. TPH is far from the silver bullet and you might want to use another pattern, but this one is good to start with.

See also:
[Entity Framework Inheritance Mapping (TPH)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438813/entity-framework-inheritance-mapping-tph) and [How to map inherited entities in EF code-first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29888160/how-to-map-inherited-entities-in-ef-code-first).